# Getting "segfault from C stack overflow" when using Rcpp to sample from std::uniform_int_distribution

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I wrote this little C++ function that works like R's `sample.int(..., replace =FALSE)` function. Essentially it draws from uniformly distributed integers and writes the results into a set until the set is of size `size`.
Maybe I'm missing something here, but I find the following behaviour quite strange. Here's a reprex:

```
#reprex.cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <random>
#include <set>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::set<unsigned long long int> sample_int(
    unsigned long long int N,
    unsigned long long int size)
{
    std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());

    // Create an empty set of integers.
    std::set<unsigned long long int> set;

    while (set.size() < size)
    {
        unsigned long long int value = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1, N)(rng);
        set.insert(value);
    }

    return set;
}

/*** R
very_big_n <- 15^16
less_big_n <- 16^15

less_big_n < very_big_n

sample_int(15^16, 10)

sample_int(16^15, 10)
*/
```

Executing this using `Rcpp` yields:

```
[R] Rcpp::sourceCpp("reprex.cpp")

[R] very_big_n <- 15^16

[R] less_big_n <- 16^15

[R] less_big_n < very_big_n
[1] TRUE

[R] sample_int(very_big_n, 10)
 [1] 114533684 182757292 493592758 712746739 751345901 804523992 867187282
 [8] 905509919 929228169 929784901

[R] sample_int(less_big_n, 10)
Error: segfault from C stack overflow
```

Am I missing something here? Why do I get that segfault when calling `sample_int` with a smaller input but not with that very large one?

Comment: The code you posted works just fine (run it here: https://godbolt.org/z/aobh9f418).  The error is somewhere else.

Comment: "Works just fine" is relative. The PRNG is reset every time the function is called. Better to instantiate the PRNG only once, and let it actually run through its state. And there's no checking that `N` and `size` have values that will allow the while loop to exit cleanly.

Comment: For example, what's stopping me from passing `N = 10` and `size = 100`? I've just broken the function. Finally, I'm curious about the efficacy of this approach versus simply generating the range, shuffling, and taking the first `size` elements. If `N == size == some large number`, it would take a very very very long time to generate all unique values in a pseudo-random fashion.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. How do I Instantiate the PRNG only once? Generating the sequence is going to be quite memory intensive if N gets large isn't it? In my applications n is significantly smaller than N.

Comment: @sweenish  Works just fine with the arguments provided, this should remove all 'relativity' from my statement.

Comment: Works fine with safe arguments is like 25% of the battle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to judge whether or not your code is effective, optimized or in general safe.

I will however answer your question, the answer lies within this line of code (the error is enclosed in double asterix):

```
unsigned long long int value = std::uniform_int_distribution**<int>**(1, N)(rng);
```

By changing the template type to unsigned long long i.e.:

```
unsigned long long int value = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long>(1, N)(rng);
```

You fix your stack overflow. And your function should now work with "very large" numbers. The fact that it didn't happen with "very big n" is just a coincidence.

The stack overflow happens within this function - one of the interval checks for the formula that generates the random number fails. That is because the upper limit is the one that overflows, i.e. after replicating the same error you experienced and going through the stacktrace you will get a more meaningful error message, something like this:

```
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/uniform_int_dist.h:97:
 std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>::param_type::param_type(_IntType, _IntType) 
[with _IntType = int]: Assertion '_M_a <= _M_b' failed.
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: As Dirk Eddelbuettel mentioned in the comments using unsigned long long is an archaic from old times. Even though that in the STL documentation they state that std::uniform_int_distribution might have undefined behavior when not using any of the suggested template types, uint64_t should still work fine (I've skimmed through the implementation). The added benefit is that uint64_t is consistent across different architectures. To use the uint64_t integer type you just need to include this header:

```
#include <cstdint>
```

Comment: Good answer.  I would add that `unsigned long long int` is both old-school and unclear. We have had explicit types 'forever' and `uint64_t` will likely do what you need.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I agree with your statement, it's also good noting that unsigned long long may be different across systems. However I also have to add that using uint64_t may have undefined behavior when using it as a template type in std::uniform_int_distribution<T> as is stated in documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: That makes little sense (as those types are being platform-dependent).  Anyway: <shrug> from here as `Rcpp::evalCpp(sizeof("uint64_t"))` gives the same value as putting `unsigned long long int` in.  It is 2022, and we have been on 64-bit cpus for years now. The value of `long long` is (to me at least) largely "historical".

Comment: I've just had to make a sanity check that the implementation of std::uniform_int_distribution<T> is fine with uint64_t before I edit my answer. It is and I've just as you posted this additional comment, updated my answer :).

Comment: Yup :)  All good and nice improvement. You did miss the final l in my overly complicated family name though.  As I usually say, referring to just 'Dirk' is much easier <wink>

Comment: Hah! My bad, it's been a long day for me:) fixed and thanks for the input!

Comment: In my case the function seems to call itself recursively and hence the stack overflow and segfault as the author mentions. 
```0x0000000000407079 in int std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::operator()<std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul, 2636928640ul, 15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul> >(std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul, 2636928640ul, 15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul>&, std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type const&) ()```